# When using ffmpeg to compress and create in real time mpeg4 video file from bathc of images getting low quality video how can i improve quality?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ffmpeg

The goal here is to create a compressed mp4 video file in real time. I'm saving screenshots as bitmaps type on my hard disk. And i want to create mp4 file and compress the mp4 video file in real time.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace Youtube_Manager
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            Logger.Write("workingDirectory: " + workingDirectory);
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);
            Logger.Write("FfmpegFilename: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {

                string outPath = pathFileName;
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            try
            {
                int length;
                // Lock the bitmap's bits.
                //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);

                int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
                // Get the address of the first line.
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
                length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

                //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
                int j = bmp.Height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                    j--;
                }
                p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error: " + err.ToString());
            }

        }

        public void Close()
        {
            p.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The Bitmaps images files on my hard disk each one is 1920x1080 and Bit depth 32.

The video file is on the hard disk at size 1.24MB

This is a screenshot i took from the video file when playing it.
You can see how bad the quality is.

[image: screenshot from video bad quality]

This is a link for 10 images of the screenshots i'm using creating from the video file. They are Bitmaps.

[Screenshots rar](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1345&authkey=!AP6_vdjPjYPo-8Q&ithint=file%2Crar)

Its something with the arguments:
This line dosen't work when i run the program the command prompt window close at once. I can't even see if there is any erorr/s the command prompt window close too fast.

```
psi.Arguments = @"-f libx264 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt bgra -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
```

When i'm using this arguments it's working but making bad quality video:

```
psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaking the input parameters from the output ones.

The first part of your command should be :

```
@"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe
```

This tells ffmpeg to expect a pipe with raw images using a bgra pixel format and a 1080p size.

Then the second part - the output parameters - for a better quality :

```
-c:v libx264 -crf 20 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
```

Make sure that *outPath* has a .mp4 or .mkv extension as H.264 can't be muxed into .avi.

You can adjust the value of crf depending on your needs. A lower value will have better quality and a bigger file size, a higher value the opposite. I recommend crf values in a 17-24 range.

Comment: Open a cmd.exe, go to your directory and run the command..? Also, you seem to have forgotten a space after '-r'.

Comment: Yes the space after the -r my mistake sorry. It's working perfect now thank you.